# python sorting changes values of previous variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

`temp` variable which is assigned before sorting is also gets `sorted` why?

and what is the best way to create a temporary variable for list.

```
>>> arr = [3, 2, 4, 1]
>>> temp = arr
>>> arr.sort()
>>> arr
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> temp
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

whereas:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = a
>>> a
5
>>> b
5
>>> a = 1000
>>> a
1000
>>> b
5
```

Comment: Dont do temp = arr, make a copy instead.

Comment: `temp = arr` means they are both names for the same `list`.

Comment: You can create a [**`sorted`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) list from another sequence: `arr = sorted(temp)`. See also [How To: sorting](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Comment: Your first and second pieces of code are not really parallel. If you were to change `arr.sort()` to `arr = sorted(arr)`, you would then be reassigning `arr` to a different object instead of changing the one it was referring to. The basic idea is that objects do not have names; names refer to objects. You can have multiple names referring to the same object. Making a name point to a different object doesn't effect the other name, but changing the object itself is reflected in all names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is worth noting that using `.sort()` modifies the original list, whereas `sorted()` will return a new sorted list. [This](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) website has a good explanation for the topic.

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is a name pointing to the same list. To create a copy of the list, you can do

```
temp = list(arr)
```

and you should see that if you run

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
temp = list(arr)
temp[0] = 2
arr != temp # will return true because it is a new object
```

Comment: `temp` is a name, not a pointer. Python doesn't have pointers. Names cannot be null.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @PeterWood. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Since they are asking about sorting as well, is it worth noting that using .sort() modifies the original list, whereas sorted() will return a new sorted list.

Comment: @Jeremy that should be an answer, not a comment.